# Resize of SVG element mouse losing "grip" on edge

Tags: reactjs, svg

I am trying to construct some SVG shapes which should be resize-able along one or more edges.

The way I do this is by creating an additional shape on top of the shape which I want to be able to resize. I use this shape to indicate to the user that an edge can be clicked on and dragged. This shape tends to be a line that lights up once the user moves their mouse over it and I change it's position while resizing the main shape.

Using a combination of the `mousedown`, `mousemove` and `mouseup` events, I get the mouse's current position and adjust the shape accordingly.

All seems to work. However, what I can't seem to figure out is that should I move my mouse a little bit too quickly, while dragging the edge, it seems as though the mouse looses track of the event and the dragging of the edge fails. At this point I am have to find the edge again and restart the process.

Any idea how to either stop the mouse from losing the edge while dragging? Or perhaps slow down the event so as not to allow the mouse to jerk into any one direction too fast?

I have created a [a sandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/resize-svg-element-mouse-edge-drag-5q0qj) to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: You are using `element.addEventListener("mouseout"`. When you move the mouse fast you easily go out of the element.  Try using `svg.addEventListener("mouseout"` or remove it alltogether.

Comment: @enxaneta thanks for the input. Would you like to add an answer to the question instead of a comment? Your comment steered me in the right direction - I separated the events of the edge from that of the resize-able rectangle. I have made the appropriate changes to the sandbox if you would like to look at it....